# Continued fraction of a sequence is unique

Tags: functions, continued-fractions

Let $X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and define a continued fraction 
$$f(X)=\cfrac{1}{x_1+\cfrac{1}{x_2+\cfrac{1}{x_3+\cfrac{1}{x_4+\cdots}}}}$$
for each element $x_i\in X$. I'm wondering if $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow [0,1]$ is injective. 
If not, would something like $$g(X)=\cfrac{|X|}{x_1+\cfrac{1}{x_2+\cfrac{1}{x_3+\cfrac{1}{x_4+\cdots}}}}$$ for a finite $X$ or 
$$h(X)=\cfrac{\bar{d}(X)}{x_1+\cfrac{1}{x_2+\cfrac{1}{x_3+\cfrac{1}{x_4+\cdots}}}}$$
for an infinite $X$, where $\bar{d}(A)$ is the upper asymptotic density of $X$, work as an injective function?

Comment: infinite continued fractions with positive integer entries have individual values. There is a rule that a finite continued fraction is not allowed to end in $1$ as that gives the one instance of duplication.

Comment: But $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ consists of finite subsets as well, so is there repetition there?

Comment: I don't think I know what $P(N)$ means, especially as you write $x_i$ also. I do know continued fractions.

Comment: @WillJagy $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of the natural numbers. Also, the $x_i$ are the elements of $X$, and since they are natural numbers we know that they can be indexed.

Comment: Are the $x_i \in X$ assumed to be ordered as $x_1 < x_2 < ...$? If $X$ is finite (having $n$ elements), do you stop with $ ..+ 1/x_n$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, you would stop at $x_n$. And I think that since $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ we can have it ordered $x_1<x_2<\cdots$.

Comment: Okay - if the $x_i$ are not assumed to be ordered, then $f(X)$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Why would there be a $0$ term if $X$ is a set of natural numbers?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Is it not possible to allow each set to be ordered since they are made up of natural numbers?

Comment: It **is** possible, but it's not what $X\in\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ means. So $f(X)$ is not well defined. For instance, if $X=\{1,2\}$, then $f(X)$ could be either $\dfrac13$ or $\dfrac23$. But it can't be **both**, or $f$ is not a function. And continued fractions with repeating terms are not even possible with this notation. It's easy to amend, though: replace $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ with the set of finite or infinite lists of integers (the question about $0$ is only a detail, though it's worth mentionning).

Comment: @BillStevens You could write this set $L=\Bbb N^\Bbb N\,\cup\,\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bbb N^{\Bbb N_n}$ with $\Bbb N_n=\{k\,|\,k\in\Bbb N\wedge k\le n\}$, and the convention that $0\notin\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The definition of $f(X)$ in the question is perhaps not very clear, but it has a reasonable interpretation to be well-defined. Let $S$ denote the set of (finite or infinite) strictly increasing sequences of integers. Then there is a canonical bijection $b : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to S$. Defining $F : S \to [0,1]$ via continued fractions as in the question, we have $f = F \circ b$. I guess the purpose of the question was to construct an injection $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})  \to [0,1]$ which was successfully done.

Comment: @PaulFrost I see. I assumed that the OP wanted to consider general continued fractions, that is without the constraint that $x_1<x_2<\dots$. But indeed, the question makes sense if we only consider this case. However, injectivity is easy, as the continued fraction is unique for such numbers as you notice in your answer. One could do that directly by considering two tentatively equivalent c.f., proving $x_1=y_1$, removing the first term, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ is injective (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). Infinite sets produce irrational numbers, finite sets rational numbers.

Each irrational number is the value of a *unique* infinite continued fraction.

Each rational number can be represented in exactly two ways as a finite continued fraction, but only in one of them the $x_i$ have a chance to be increasing.